# Pause MediaPlayer android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

So I have mediaplayer which plays audio files from the phone. To play them i use this code for the Play button

```
     try {
         if (mp2.isPlaying()) {
             mp2.reset();
      }
         mp2.setDataSource(s1); //using path here
         mp2.prepare();
         mp2.start();
         mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method 
                    mp.reset();
                }
            });
     } catch (Exception e) {

     }
```

I want to pause the song and continue to play it with the same code, I tried `mp2.pause();`
but if i click on play button nothing will happen. I dont wanna to remove `if (mp2.isPlaying()) {
             mp2.reset();
      }`

Comment: this code has three MediaPlayers - mp, mp1, mp2
Is that a typo?
If not, you might want to add the reset of the code so we can better understand your question

Comment: sorry about that, I fixed it, i dont think i need more lines of code s1 is string with path on pause button i've got mp2.pause();